# Facebook share Website content and URL

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer, facebook-sdk-3.0

i am running a Religious website. I just want to share the website URL in which Video is playing.

[http://ਏਕਤੂਹੀ.com/view-video/442/](http://%E0%A8%8F%E0%A8%95%E0%A8%A4%E0%A9%82%E0%A8%B9%E0%A9%80.com/view-video/442/)

**Problem : after click on Sharing button POP is not closing and no any sharing found on my FB profile page.**

Here i am using

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=myappid&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://ਏਕਤੂਹੀ.com/view-video/<?php echo $videoId;?>/" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

In APP setting i have set 
Site URL: `http://ਏਕਤੂਹੀ.com/`

I also tried with [How to add facebook share button on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463030/how-to-add-facebook-share-button-on-my-website/23822510#)
Post answers but my query not seems to be solved.