# Php Facebook share link

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, share

I have a website with some Facebook "Share" buttons.
The  Facebook "Share" button was working properly until a few days. I haven't touch the code in the meantime.
Now, I get a notification "Not found- back to Facebook", each time I click on the share button in my website.

Here is an example of a link for sharing:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]Mytitle=&p[summary]MySummary=&p[url]=http://www.tribalartmagazine.com/index.php?content=article&section=news&id=360&lang=en&p[image]=http://www.tribalartmagazine.com/assets/data/news/n360.jpg

Thank you for your help as I really don't see the problem.

I searched but I've seen nowhere that Facebook has changed the attributes of the shared links lately so I really don't know what should be done.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463030/how-to-add-facebook-share-button-on-my-website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlencode` only the arguments, not everything, also, the correct url is: 
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php
not
<strike>https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php</strike>

```html
    <a class="element1_item_facebook_on" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=&p[summary]=&p[url]=http%3a%2f%2fwww.tribalartmagazine.com%2findex.php%3fcontent%3darticle%26section%3dnews%26id%3d433%26lang%3den&p[image]=http%3a%2f%2fwww.tribalartmagazine.com%2fassets%2fdata%2fnews%2fn433.jpg">Share Me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. It was that. What i don't get is that it was working before and I didn't change anything since. Anyway, it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer!  You're right, it is sharer/sharer.php, according to docs (click "get code" and see Url generated https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/).  But both seem to work: https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.revoltlib.com