# Why does my facebook share button not work?

Tags: jquery, facebook-sharer

This the [twitter equivalent](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%22Only%20those%20who%20dare%20to%20fail%20greatly%20can%20ever%20achieve%20greatly.%20%22-Robert%20Kennedy) of what I want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#facebook').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent('Hello'));
});
});
```

```css
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px
}

body{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:red;
 /*center the button*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  /*background image properties*/
  background:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/98/a5/cf/98a5cf91e8aef10a2b81303a7ccbce9e.jpg) fixed no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
.button{
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:blue;
  border-radius:10px;
  /*enter the f inside the box*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
 /*size of the f*/
  font-size:180px; 
  /*frosty glass effect*/
  background:inherit;
  z-index:1;
  /*removing position will spread the blur onto the entire page.*/
  position:relative;
  /*hides the blurry edge*/
  overflow:hidden;
}

.button::before{
  background:inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  /*This is not blurring. This makes it paler/less colorful*/
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  /*Sharpen the edge*/
  margin:-20px;
  filter:blur(10px);
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  /*THIS is where the blur effect appears*/
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
/*Hover the cursor effect*/
.button:hover::before{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
/*Click effect*/
.button:active::before{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}


.position{
  position:relative;
  left:30px;
  top:23px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a class='button' id='facebook'><i class="fa fa-facebook position"></i></a>
```

You are supposed click on that facebook icon and get to share 'Hello'.I did the same with twitter just that the link in JQuery in different. I saw this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16464986/4747885) on stack overflow. I built this on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/OgxxxY?editors=0010). The new tab will pop out on Chrome and disappear.

Comment: It's because links pop up and disappear just retrun false in your function which works on click event like so. 'return false'

Comment: @Saqlain Why is it returning false? The thing works with Twitter link.

Comment: If you are bothered just google it or except use a button or input type submit