# Return current URL for a share button

Tags: javascript, html, url, href, share-button

I'm new in web development and I'm trying to insert the current URL into href for a Facebook share button using JS. I tried in the following way but as you can see it's not correct.

```js
function getURL() {
    return window.location.href;
}
```

```html
<div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com" 
    data-layout="button" 
    data-size="small">
      <a target="_blank" 
        href="getURL()" 
        class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        Share
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean by clicking on the share button you will move Facebook share page??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add facebook share button on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463030/how-to-add-facebook-share-button-on-my-website)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<script>
    document.querySelector('a').setAttribute("href",  window.location.href);
</script>


<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.facebook.com" data-layout="button" data-size="small"><a target="_blank" href="" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" id='facebook-share'>Share</a></div>
```

Comment: It'd be safer to select the `a` element by `id` (`document.getElementById('facebook-share') `)

Answer (score 0):

In your tag `<a>` add `id`

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button" data-size="small"><a target="_blank" id="btnsharefb" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
```

And create listener to event click to your tag `a`

```
document.getElementById("btnsharefb").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.href = getURL();
});
```

OR add directly on load document

```
document.getElementById("btnsharefb").href = getURL();
```

E.g. https://codepen.io/darlandieterich/pen/abNrmWO